# I get "Assembly outside lib folder" warning when assembly is actually inside the lib

Tags: c#, .net, nuget

Here's the error I get:

```
>./NuGet.exe pack MyAssembly.nuspec
Attempting to build package from 'MyAssembly.nuspec'.
Successfully created package 'V:\...\MyAssembly\bin\Publish\MyAssembly.0.0.0.nupkg'.
WARNING: Issue found with package 'MyAssembly'.

WARNING: Issue: Assembly outside lib folder.
WARNING: Description: The assembly 'lib/net46/MyAssembly.dll' is not inside the 'lib' folder and hence it won't be added as reference when the package is installed into a project.
WARNING: Solution: Move it into the 'lib' folder if it should be referenced.
```

And here's include I use:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<package>
  <metadata>
    <id>MyAssembly</id>
    <version>0.0.0</version>
    <authors>Poma</authors>
    <description>MyAssembly</description>
  </metadata>
  <files>
    <file src="MyAssembly.dll" target="lib/net46/" />
  </files>
</package>
```

I checked with NuGet Explorer and dll is indeed in lib/net46. What could be wrong here?

**Update:** this happens with NuGet 3.5 and 4.1 but doesn't happen with 3.4

Comment: Try to move it to 'lib' instead to 'lib/net46'

Comment: In that case I get "dll is not in framework folder" error

Comment: I did not find different between using a ``/`` and ``\``, but [all examples](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/schema/nuspec#including-assembly-files)  from `files` section use ``\``. Did you try to set path with backslash?

Answer (score 5):

As George said, use backslash `\` instead of forward slash `/` in your target and the warning should go away (reproduced with nuget `4.3.0.440`).

Answer (score 0):

I tried the \ instead of forward slash / to no avail.

But, updating Nuget.exe to the latest version *worked a treat* :)

```
sudo nuget update -self

Checking for updates from https://www.nuget.org/api/v2/.
Currently running NuGet.exe 4.3.0.
Updating NuGet.exe to 4.7.1.
Update successful.
```